# Can't Fetch Data from REST call in BackBone: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, rest, backbone.js, jsonp

I am having issues retrieving json data from a REST endpoint using Backbone. It will console.log the entire json source, but gives me an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error for actual values within the JSON output. I am able to retrieve data as desired using a straight AJAX call to my REST endpoint as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "http://myajaxcall.com/articles/featured",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.aside, function (index, value) {
            console.log(value.headLine);
        });
    }
            });
```

But I am unable to get BackBone to fetch the same data. Where in my fetch am I going wrong?

```
    var featuredArticle = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        headLine: '',
        snippet: '',
        fullStory: '',
        location: '',
        nsfw: '',
        category: '',
        relatedArticleIds: '',
        hasVideoPlaceholder: '',
        numberOfImages: ''
    }
});
var featuredArticles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: featuredArticle,
    url: 'http://myajaxcall.com/articles/featured'
});

var articleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var getfeaturedArticles = new featuredArticles();
        getfeaturedArticles.fetch({
            dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(getfeaturedArticles);
            $.each(data.aside, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value.headline);
                $(that.el).append('<li>' + value.headLine + '</li>');
            });
        }
        })

        return this;
    }
});
var articles = new articleView();
$("body").append(articles.render().el);
```

Comment: I get the same error of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Are you using chrome? You can check the network tab to what you get back from the server. What you need to console log is the data parameter, not the collection object itself.

Comment: Yes I am. Can you provide an example of logging the data parameter?

Comment: That returns the entire json object. My issues is trying to get something from that object, such as the data for a headline.

Comment: It has an array named aside that contains the property of headline. Any clue why my straight ajax call works for this, but the backbone fetch doesn't?

Comment: I cleaned up some comments. Check the answer, that should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback should be like this:

```
success: function(model, response)  {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: I looked over it initially. Glad it helped.

Comment: Final question, can you breakdown why I need both the "model" and "response" for the function. "Response" or "Variable" doesn't work alone.

Comment: You don't necessarily need them both. The 'model' parameter in the example returns the model with objects as an array property, while the response parameter (call it whatever you like) immediately returns an array of objects. If you call model.toJSON() on the model variable, you'll notice that you get the same result.

Comment: Returning the array is what I needed. Thanks again for all your help!